# Send info regarding user via XMPP in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I have implemented the chat and everything is working good. I follow that link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/ tutorial to implement chat app. Now i want to send info regarding user like photo,birthday,nickname etc. So i just want to create that info and send to other user.

I also want to send image(Data) to another user.

Comment: Hi, i am also working on chat development. But i can't get file/image transfer via chat, did you get this thing working? Also i have did lot of search on google and stack-overflow, but did not get any working idea/code.So please suggest me if you get this thing working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah i have done that @sunil z

Comment: oh great!! please, can you tell me how to implement file/image transfer via chat in iphone?

Comment: NSXMLElement *photo = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
            NSXMLElement *binval = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL"];
            [photo addChild:binval];
            [binval setStringValue:[dataPic base64Encoded]];
            [message addChild:photo];
@sunilz : use this

Comment: Hi i think this code is for update vCard avatar, but i wnat to send image/file from one user to another user via chat. Is it possible? Also i have tried above code but did not get work. Can you explore full code for this?

Comment: @sunilz : bro this is for sending image via chat. where u send message  add these in that... so have u done v cards?

Comment: Hi i have tried above code and message sent but not get sent image..

Comment: and got following logs:-   SEND: <iq type="error" to="proxy.sunils.local" id="C8BEAEF2-C2D5-4BBE-BD5A-6B74767EF70A"><error code="404" type="cancel"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

Comment: RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="1D9F07D5-F83F-471F-A72E-E002D530D972" from="brijesh@sunils.local" to="sunil@sunils.local/385fea69"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="1D9F07D5-F83F-471F-A72E-E002D530D972" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="proxy.sunils.local" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/></query><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

Comment: AppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: - 1D9F07D5-F83F-471F-A72E-E002D530D972
TURN Connection failed!   <TURNSocket: 0x80acab0>

Comment: Any solution? Also can you explore working code if you have any? also v cards thing is not get done currently..

Comment: http://pastie.org/6346052 check out this

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17847/cocos2d

Comment: Get same error again using code at http://pastie.org/6346052 . Will this thing work with iphone simulator? Which server you have used for that? Can provide me demo code for that?

Comment: @PraviJayI am creating an app, where i need to add chat option...can you pls guide me or send me any tutorial link that will be helpful for me...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an avatar and other user-information you should have a look at the vcard extension XEP-0153 ([specification](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0054) and [implementation](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0054)).

You will find an example implementation for the vCard within the [XMPPFramework iphone demo](https://github.com/NoilPaw/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate.m).
You would use the following calls to update and fetch vCards:

```
- (XMPPvCardTemp *)fetchvCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid;
- (XMPPvCardTemp *)fetchvCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid useCache:(BOOL)useCache;
- (void)updateMyvCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp;
```

To send binary data, you have some options. The XMPPFramework [implements](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Extensions/XEP-0065/TURNSocket.h) XEP-0065. There are other methods to send data like:

- [XEP-0066: Out of Band Data](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html)
- [XEP-0096: SI File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html)
- [XEP-0234: Jingle File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0234.html)

Which you could probably implement as extensions and integrate them into the XMPPFramework.

In will integrate sending binary data like images and videos myself soon. So please leave a comment about your implementation.

Comment: its too helpful but can u send me little coding part. if u have done that. it will give an idea

Comment: hey man i updated my vCard but can't fetch xmppvCardTemp. can u give me the code of that. if u can then paste the code in pastie.com and send the link to me thanx

Comment: @PraviJay: We don't use the vcard yet. But have a look at the demo-implementation of the xmppframework. They integrated the vcard and it did work for me.
[xmppframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP/Classes/iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate.m)

Comment: can u help me in v-card because i m really stuck in it

Comment: With their code you should be able to just use:
`- (XMPPvCardTemp *)fetchvCardTempForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid` of the CardTempModule, and with that you have all the data you need.
Or update it with `- (void)updateMyvCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp`.

Comment: yeah i know but its not working man i don't know why. with this i get XMPPvCardTemp = nil

Comment: Sorry, i looked into it, but i don't get the expected results, too. I guess you have to dig deeper.

Comment: hey bro i fetched XMPPvCardTemp object by "XMPPvCardTemp *vCard2 = [objDelegate.xmppvCardTempModule  fetchvCardTempForJID:objDelegate.xmppStream.myJID];  "  but i get nil. m i doing rite or not

Comment: Sounds the right way to do it. I will let you know, when i use vCards.

Answer (score 0):

first setup user profire in [spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) and then use [XMPPvCardTempModule myvCardTemp]